# Multiple .conf files subdomains using nginx

Tags: wordpress, dns, nginx, webserver

Under my domain, say `example.com`, I want to have a landing page (which will surface when hitting `example.com`), a WordPress blog (which will live at `blog.example.com`) and my resume in HTML (which will live at `resume.example.com`).  Using nginx, I want to have three separate .conf files so that I can bring them up and down separate from each other.  The DNS is set up such that "resume" and "blog" are A records for `example.com`.

I'm running this on a Linode, so I have full control over DNS and the web server.  However, when I try to split the nginx .conf entry for `blog.example.com` into a separate file, I get a redirect from `blog.example.com` to `www.example.com` when I hit this in a web browser.

I know the install of WordPress isn't the problem, because when all three server entries are in one nginx file, everything works fine.  I have also tried creating a separate folder structure for the blog (`blogs-available` and `blogs-enabled`) then including those folders in the `nginx.conf` **before** the `sites-enabled` include, but that didn't work either.  This leaves me with two questions:

1. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get this to work?  Perhaps my DNS settings are incorrect.
2. Does nginx care about the load order or is it ambiguous?  If it's the latter, then I'll keep everything in one server block and either have them all up or all down.

UPDATE:

nginx.conf for `example.com`:

```
# Blog (WordPress site - blog.example.com)
server {
  listen <ip-address>;
  server_name blog.example.com;
  root /www/blog.example.com/public_html/current;

  access_log /www/blog.example.com/logs/access.log;
  error_log /www/blog.example.com/logs/error.log;

  location / {
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /www/blog.example.com/public_html/current/$fastcgi_script_name;

    if ($uri !~ "^/images/") {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
    }
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }
}

# redirect example.com to www.example.com
server {
  listen <ip-address>;
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
  break;
}

# static site - www.example.com
server {
  listen <ip-address>;
  server_name www.example.com;
  # static HTML / soon-to-be Sinatra site
  root /www/example.com/public_html/current/public;

  access_log /www/example.com/logs/access.log;
  error_log /www/example.com/logs/error.log;
}
```

Note:  I don't have the `resume.example.com` site above, but that should be trivial.  Also, the above work in any order, so I don't believe it's a redirect issue.

** 2nd Update **

On a hunch, I commented out the following in my `example.com` conf file:

```
server {
    listen <ip-address>:80;
        server_name example.com;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
        break;
    }
```

And it worked as I expected.  Is there something wrong with my non-www -> www redirect rule above?

Comment: Is that a 301 redirect or just the content is from www.example.com? Post your config file here and we can have more concrete suggestion. btw, this should be an easy setup in nginx to support multiple domains in one server.

Comment: nginx conf is fine. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For 2nd question, nginx config is declarative. The server block order doesn't matter. So it's easy to manage each server block in its own .conf file.

**UPDATE** After seeing the nginx config file

can't find anything wrong with the nginx conf file. Tried it in my devbox and it worked fine. So it could be from dns setup. One possibility is that you setup "blog" as a CNAME record of "www" (a cname record is an alias). e.g.,

```
blog   IN   CNAME   www
```

If that's the case, a web browser will send http://blog.example.com to http://www.example.com.

Also note that dns record could be cached inside your browser, or in your isp dns server. Even if you fix it for a while, the wrong record may still be cached. Try

```
dig blog.example.com
```

to obtain some information of the dns setup.

Comment: When I do `dig blog.example.com`, I get back `blog.example.com <TTL> IN A <ip-address>` ... The IP returned is the same IP as all other sites that live at that IP address.  Do I need a separate DNS entry for `blog.example.com`?

Comment: DNS entry is good then. Do you have redirects inside your php code that might hardcode the redirect domain name?

Comment: Nope.  It seems like the redirect for the non-www domain might be catching the `blog` portion of the URL and redirecting it.  Is this possible?

Comment: Should not. But you can remove that server block to verify if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Do you have `curl` installed? You may try this to find more clue: `curl -IvL http://blog.example.com` and see what's the header info being exchanged, especially the `HOST` and `Location` headers. Do you see `HTTP/1.1 301`?

Comment: I removed the `blog.example.com` entry from the `example.com` nginx conf, put it in its own conf file, and added the new conf to `sites-enabled`.  I then ran the above and the results was:  `HTTP/1.1 301` with `Connection #0 to host blog.example.com left intact.  Issue another request to this URL: 'http://www.example.com'`

Comment: Does this mean there is a DNS issue?

Comment: Looks like a normal 301 redirect msg. Did you check the blog site's nginx access log `/www/blog.example.com/logs/access.log` to see if the request actually reaches blog.example.com?

Comment: I see that you have these `listen <ip-address>;` lines. Are they using the same ip address? Normally you don't need to listen to a specific ip address in most use cases. I'd prefer to use `listen 80;`, which will listen to all ip addresses on your server.

Comment: For comment 1:  Yeah, I just tried that.  When I have a separate nginx entry for blog.example.com, nothing hits the logs.

Comment: For comment 2: I do that because I'm running a Linode with two IP addresses.  I guess if I'm matching on the server name, I still could simply do `listen 80;`, right?

Comment: Any other ideas?  Thanks again for all your ideas and help!

Comment: I tried your exact conf file in my own devbox and it worked just fine. Did you by accident put a dot "." in front of your server name? e.g. `.example.com` instead of `example.com`. A server name with a leading dot will match all sub-domains. That's the only thing I can think of now.

Comment: Nope, no leading dot.  Could I do `server_name $scheme://example.com` to match the non-www?  Think that might work?

Comment: Have you tried `nginx -t` to see if nginx complains about your `blog.example.com` server block?